# how to append forms based on input with svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, supabase

can someone help me understand this please.
I want when someone enters a number, that 2 forms appear and the data from those forms would go into a new object that i can push to supabase

for example

```
let num = 2
let formData = [{ name: '' }];

const add = async (formData) => {
        try {
            const { error } = await supabase.from('name').upsert(formData);
            if (error) throw error;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        } finally {
            console.log('success');
        }
    };
```

this is the input to select how much forms should appear

```
<input type="number" class="bg-transparent" bind:value={num} />
```

this is me iterating and adding the formdata.name but a new object isnt being added

```
{#each Array(num) as i}
        <form action="">
            {#each formData as meh}
                <input bind:value={meh.name} placeholder="name" type="text" class="bg-transparent" />
            {/each}
        </form>
{/each}
```

I want to receive this

```
let formData = [{ name: 'name1' }, { name: 'name2' }]
```

however, its only remaining like

```
let formData = [{ name: 'name1' }];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that there's no "connection" between `Array(num)` and formData.
One possible solution would be to build `formData` reactively based on `num` like this >> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/09e29cc79a414498b4550dc414f7bd00?version=3.47.0)

```
<script>
    let num = 2
    
    $: formData = Array.from({length: num}, value => {return { name: '' }})
    
    $: console.log(num, formData)

    const add = async (formData) => {
        //      ...
    };
</script>

<input type="number" class="bg-transparent" bind:value={num} />

<form action="">
    {#each formData as f, index}
    <label>f{index+1}
    <input bind:value={f.name} placeholder="name" type="text" class="bg-transparent" />
        </label>
    {/each}
</form>
```

While this covers the basic functionality, all inputs get reset when `num` changes. In case you would like to keep already entered data when an element is added or removed, this would be an approach to do so >> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c4a8ddfbacd04eaba75cb4988b60bbc2?version=3.47.0)

```
<script>
    let num = 2
    let formData = []

    $: adjustFormData(num)

    function adjustFormData(num) {
        const difference = num - formData.length
        if(difference > 0) {
            formData.push(...Array.from({length:difference}, value => {return { name: '' }}))
            formData = formData
        }else {
            formData = formData.slice(0, difference)
        }
    }

    $: console.log(num, formData)

    const add = async (formData) => {
        //      ...
    };
</script>

<input type="number" class="bg-transparent" bind:value={num} />

<form action="">
    {#each formData as f, index}
    <label>f{index+1}
        <input bind:value={f.name} placeholder="name" type="text" class="bg-transparent" />
    </label>
    {/each}
</form>
```

Comment: Hey thanks alot for this. I found this from reddit and was able to understand it a little better. https://svelte.dev/repl/e4b8f9a42fcd4774ac754fa7db1f5675?version=3.47.0 .. the problem im having is if i click the add button. It adds a new object but it should first check to see if it exsist already and either update or add